# Action of complex operator on (real) normal distribution

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution, complex-numbers

Let $\mathbf{x}$ be an N-dimensional (real) random variable following a multivariate normal distribution, $\mathbf{x}\sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{\Sigma})$. If $\mathbf{A}$ is a real linear operator, a standard result states that $\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{Ax}\sim\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{A}\boldsymbol{\mu},\mathbf{A}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}\mathbf{A^T})$.

What happens if $\mathbf{A}$ is allowed to have complex entries?

Comment: You need to replace transpose with the Hermitean conjugate and then make sure you continue to view $\mathbf y$ as a *real* vector-valued random variable.